# Unable to load the jquery grid on post in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have 2 views , first the Index displaying jquery grid.
second is the entry page Customer
After insertion i redirect to Index() in the controller again but onload the grid is not displayed,below is the jquery function for grid
JqueryGrid code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Search();
    });

    function Search() {
       var jqDataUrl = "QueueMgmt/LoadData";
       var reportName = "WallBoard";
       $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
           url: jqDataUrl,
           datatype: "json",
           mtype: "POST",
           postData: {  },
           colNames: ["QUEUE", "CIQ", "Avail", "Staff"],
           colModel: [
            { name: "QUEUE_NO", index: "QUEUE_NO", align: "left" },
            { name: "CIQ", index: "CIQ", align: "left" },
            { name: "Avail", index: "Avail", align: "left" },
            { name: "Staff", index: "Staff", align: "left" } 
            ],
           autowidth: true,
           viewrecords: true,
           sortname: "QUEUE_NO",
           sortorder: "asc",
           caption: reportName,
           onSelectRow: function (id) {
               rowSelected(id);
           }
       });
       $("#jqTable").parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv');  
    }
    </script>
```

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult LoadData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
     {
         try
         {
             // Get the list
             var configs = MMDataprocess.Select().AsQueryable();
             var filteredconfigs = configs;                

             // Sort the  list
             var sortedConfigs = SortIQueryable<QueueMgmtModel>(filteredconfigs, sidx, sord);

             // Calculate the total number of pages
             var totalRecords = filteredconfigs.Count();
             var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / (double)rows);

             // Prepare the data to fit the requirement of jQGrid
             var data = (from s in sortedConfigs
                         select new
                         {
                             id = s.QUEUE_NO,
                             cell = new object[] {s.QUEUE_NO,s.CIQ,s.Avail,s.Staff}
                         }).ToArray();

             // Send the data to the jQGrid
             var jsonData = new 
             {
                 total = totalPages,
                 page = page,
                 records = totalRecords,
                 rows = data.Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows)

             };
            return Json(jsonData);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         }

         return null;
     }
```

Since I am new to MVC ,Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Try placing a debugger in LoadData. Is your jqGrid able to hit controller action ? I suspect on this line `var jqDataUrl = "QueueMgmt/LoadData";`.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow in controller return statement

```
 return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```